# Is it valid to dereference this pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
struct myclass{
    static const int invalid = -1;
    /*explicit*/ myclass(int i, double d = 0.0){
        _var = i
    }
    int _var; 
    bool operator < (const myclass& rhs);
    bool operator > (const myclass& rhs);
    bool operator == (const myclass& rhs);
    bool operator != (const myclass& rhs);
    /*
    bool operator == (int rhs){
        return *(this) == myclass(rhs); // Is this valid C++ ?
    }
    bool operator != (int rhs){
        return *(this) == myclass(rhs); // Is this valid C++ ?
    }
    */
};

int userCodeCall() {
    myclass m(10);
    
    // Valid use Case
    if(m != myclass::invalid) {
        //.... do something
    }
    
    // Invalid use case
    if(m < 0.5) { // I want this to give me a compiler error
        //.... do something
    }
    // Invalid use case
    if(m < 5) { // I want this to give me a compiler error
        //.... do something
    }
}
```

I am working on a legacy codebase and I came across a class that can be implicitly constructed from int. And I found a bug where we were performing a < than comparison with a double. I thought of fixing this using an explicit with the constructor and then separately defining a == operation with an integer. But, I am not comfortable with the design. As I haven't seen this pattern anywhere else.

```
bool operator == (int rhs){
    return *(this) == myclass(rhs); // Is this valid C++ ?
}
```

I have two questions?

1. Is it valid C++11/14/17?
2. Can the design of the class be improved upon? Given I still want to have a "==" comparison style usage to stay valid as it is all over the user codebase.

   ```
   if(m != myclass::invalid) // some similar API need to be supported, if not the same.
   ```

Comment: I have messed up the variable name. Lets say it is _var. Also I am using != in the use case and have defined == operator in the class. I need both of them in the use case. So, lets say I define both of them in the class too.,

Comment: Please add all clarifications, and corrections, by editing the question, instead of leaving comments.

Comment: The only ways to create an invalid `this` pointer are for either the calling code or previous code to have exhibited undefined behaviour (e.g. dereferencing a NULL, creating a reference from a dangling pointer, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more common idiom for this kind of validity testing is to use an explicit operator bool:

```
struct myclass {
 private:
    static const int _invalid = -1;
    int _var;
 public:
    explicit myclass(int i, double d = 0.0){
        _var = i
    } 
    explicit operator bool() const { return _var != _invalid; }
    bool operator < (const myclass& rhs);
    bool operator == (const myclass& rhs);
    bool operator != (const myclass& rhs);
    bool operator > (const myclass& rhs);
};

int userCodeCall() {
    myclass m(10);
    
    // Valid use Case
    if(m) {
        //.... do something
    }
    
    // Invalid use case
    if(m < 0.5) { // gives a compile error
        //.... do something
    }
    // Invalid use case
    if(m < 5) { // gives a compile error
        //.... do something
    }
}
```

If this is too much and you must have a myclass::invalid to test against, you can just make it an instance of the class:

```
static constexpr myclass invalid(-1);
```

Comment: Hey Chris, I have moved forward with your recommendation. This looks like the ideal setting for me.

Answer (score 3):

The solution you have is fine, but it seems you just want to prevent specific comparison operators from working when numeric types are on the right hand side. You can do that by simply deleting those specific operators, for all types other than `myclass`.

```
template<typename T>
bool operator<(T) = delete;
    
template<typename T>
bool operator>(T) = delete;
```

Comment: I am not only worried about implicit conversions from double, but, with other numeric types also. I don't want "<" or ">" to compare my class type with any other numeric type. I want to catch all such usages during compile time.

Comment: @Manish define a template constructor that is enabled only for integral/floating-point types using SFINAE, and then mark it as `delete`d.

Comment: @Manish I've edited the answer. Now `==` and `!=` will work for integer types, but `<` and `>` won't.

Comment: @cigien, I have clarified the question further. I want to delete every comparison operation, apart from `==` and `!=`. The class is derived from boost::totally_ordered. I am not sure if my statement is the same as saying that I want to delete `<` and `>` only.

Comment: @Manish The technique in this answer is the same one you can use to delete any operators that you don't want. If this doesn't work for your case because of inheriting from `boost::totally_ordered`, you should ask a separate question, and you can link to this one. Repeatedly adding information to the question can invalidate existing answers, and is not really the right thing to do.

Comment: @cigien, I am rolled back my changes to the original question. Thanks

Comment: Let me verify that these changes will work on a class not inheriting from `boost::totally_ordered`.  The last time I checked Putting these changes in my class is disabling all the `<` and `>` comparisons. I am not sure how to specialize it and say delete every other but my class comparisons. I haven't used SFINAE before, I am aware of the concept in general though. I am also not sure if this may happen because I am inhering from `boost::totally_ordered`, but, on first look, I don't see why should that affect it. But, I will try to create a dummy class and test it.